# FQL how to link the photo_src table to other tabls

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Im trying to get the source of a photo from the photo_scr table

the example provided works

SELECT src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id = 10150931418786729

however, I have no idea what the photo_id is nor where to get it from.

Ive tried the pid from other tables but that doesnt work and ive tried oid but that doesnt work either. None of the other tables have photo_id they all have pid or object_id.

So how do I query to find photo_ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the object_id in the table "photo" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)